# Why Hibernate creates sequence for column referring on *-to-many table?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

### Hi everyone!

I faced with a strange problem. I'm trying to create a simple database schema. But hibernate creates extra sequences for columns referring on a id-columns in *-to-many tables.

I annotated ids with
`@Id`, `@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")`, `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
to create sequences for `BIGSERIAL` type (but I wouldn't like hibernate to make column with foreign key as `BIGSERIAL`).

My entities have such structure

```
    @Entity
    public class PropertyItem {

        //id's here ...

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
        private Property property;

        //getters and setters ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Property {

        //id's here ...

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "property")
        private List<PropertyItem> propertyItems;

        //getters and setters ...
    }
```

Please, help me to avoid this :(

## Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I got it!**

this annotation `@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")` is superfluous.